# Why isn't this code returning a value when ran with the __name__ == '__main__' trick?

Tags: python

Here's the code:

```
def row_check(table):
    for ealst in table:
            first = [ealst[0]]
            for each in ealst[1:]:
                    if each not in first:
                            first.append(each)
                    else:
                            return False
    return True

def col_check(table):
    col = []
    totalcol = []
    count = 0
    for rows in table:
            for columns in range(len(table)):
                    col.append(table[int(columns)][count])
            count += 1
            totalcol.append(col)
            col = []
    return totalcol

def check_sudoku(table):
    if row_check(table) and row_check(col_check(table)):
            return True
    return False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    table = [[1, 2, 3],
             [4, 5, 6],
             [7, 8, 9]]
    check_sudoku(table)
```

This isn't returning the value True. Now, when I call the function manually after the code is run, it returns the expected value:

```
>>> table
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

>>> check_sudoku(table)
True
```

Here is a minimal example that exhibits the same behaviour:

```
def check_sudoku(table):
    return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    table = [[1, 2, 3],
             [4, 5, 6],
             [7, 8, 9]]
    check_sudoku(table)
```

Why is this happening and how may I prevent this, i.e., return True when called?

Comment: In interactive session the return value is automatically echoed back to the shell.

Comment: Aside: your indentation looks weird to me.  I strongly recommend using 4-space indentation, not tabs or mixed 4/8 spaces.  (It's hard to tell what it was originally because indentation doesn't always survive pasting into SO, but it probably wasn't 4-space to start with.)

Comment: you should always try to find the minimal amount of code that shows your problem before posting your question here. it makes finding the bug much easier for us.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    table = [[1, 2, 3],
             [4, 5, 6],
             [7, 8, 9]]
    print check_sudoku(table) #you need to actually print stuff when running in a script
```

it only **prints** return values when you are in the shell. when you are running a script you must actually print anything you want printed ...

Comment: And any other behavior would be absolutely undesirable.